# Page layout displaying fields that are not available in object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, page-layout, fsl

I using FSL for our project. On the Shift object page layout, I can see two extra fields: Territory Start Time (GMT) and Territory End Time (GMT). See the image below:

[image]

However, when I go to the Setup->Shift(object)-->Fields, I do not see those two fields in the list of available fields. I also cannot see those fields in page layout:

[image]

I want to know where are those fields coming from and how do I remove them from page layout?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at are not regular fields on the page layout but [Dynamic Form](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5) fields.